# Beethoven Kreutzer string quintet

Tags: beethoven

I recently bought a boxed set of Beethoven CDs.  I had most of the works already but it was still a cost effective way to fill some gaps.

[Beethoven - Complete Masterpieces at Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000NDEMAI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

One surprising item in it was a string quintet version of the Kreutzer violin sonata.  I love the violin sonata so this was very interesting and I liked it immediately.

However, information on it seems to be sparse.  It appears that the arrangement is not by Beethoven.

What is known about this piece?

Comment: This is off-topic and should be moved to music fans.

Comment: I have just found and joined Music Fans. How do I move the question?  Just delete here and repost there or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document has some information about it

[mro.massey.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10179/4736/02_whole.pdf?sequence=1](http://mro.massey.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10179/4736/02_whole.pdf?sequence=1)

### Edit added by cellocgw

Qoting from p.42 of said document,
(apologies for the pasteup but the jackass who published this copy-locked it)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably off-topic here, nevertheless:

According to [this German sheet music publisher](http://www.pellazino.de/streicher/streichquintett-nach-der-kreutzer-sonatein-a-op-47.html) the transcription was made by an anonymous contemporary composer.

According to [that publisher](https://www.sjmusicpublications.co.uk/sheet-music/ensemble.cfm/product/beethoven-kreutzer-quintet) it was first published 1832.

While the violin part was kept practically unchanged for the first violin, the piano part was skillfully broken apart and freely adapted, with a "touch of Boccherini-like mediterranean style". The quintet is for 2 violins, viola and 2 violoncelli (as Schuberts, but also widely employed by Boccherini).

Comment: Thanks.  I have just found and joined Music Fans.  

I played it before discovering that the arrangement was not by Beethoven himself and I was quite surprised when I discovered it.